# what is the proper way to make a table from a Mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

My question is that I know there are many different way to do the same thing, but I would suspect that there is a "standard" for building tables from queries.

Looking at the 2 query/table combinations, which one is the more acceptable one? 
Is there an even more standardized version of building a table from a query?
I would like to know a "best practices" way of doing this.

I created a query a while back:

```
$query1="select concat(sp.first_name,' ',sp.last_name)as 'Player Name',st.name as 'Team', spt_league_id as 'League', ss.Season_name
from stats_player sp
inner join stats_player_team stp,stats_team st, stats_season ss
where stp.player_num = sp.player_num  and st.team_num=stp.team_id and ss.season_index=stp.season_id and stp.season_id=$this_season
order by st.League_id,st.Team_num,sp.player_num";


$result=mysql_query($query1);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
```

and then built the table with this:

```
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Player</b></font></td>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Team</b></font></td>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>League</b></font></td>
</tr>

<?php

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Player Name");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Team");
    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"League");
?>
<tr>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

I then ran across code written by someone else:

```
$query= "select first_name,last_name,email_address,name,captain_id,paid,p.player_num,league_id from stats_player p left join  stats_player_team t on p.player_num=t.player_num left join  stats_team s on t.team_id=s.team_num where season_id=$this_season and name is not NULL order by league_id,s.captain_id,name,first_name";
$results=mysql_query($query);
print "<table border=1>";
print "<tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>captain</td><td>Email?</td><td>League</td><td>Team</td><td>pay</td><td>wks played</td></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    if($row['email_address'] != NULL ){
    $email='y';
    }
    else {
    $email='n';
    }
if($row[captain_id]==$row[player_num]){ $iscapt="Captain"; }
else{$iscapt="";}
  $paid=$row[paid];
  if($paid){$playpaid="<td bgcolor=#99ff33>paid</td>";}
  else {$playpaid="<td bgcolor=#ff6633>not paid</td>";}

printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></td><td>%s</td>%s \n</tr>",$row['first_name'],$row['last_name'],$iscapt,$email,$row['league_id'],$row['name'],$playpaid);

}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: dont use <table> , use <div> instead , <table> are now considered invalid in Xhtml

Comment: @CodingAnt - do you have a link for that?

Comment: use div instead of table, and use css to align them accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to **SEPARATE** the HTML code from PHP code unless you dont have a choice.It looks clumsy and will have difficulty in handling things in future. Moreover it will also take more time in loading the page.

Your first code is more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is identical and the performance is identical, then the more readable code is "better".

However, the first does not output valid HTML5 or XHTML because it uses deprecated attributes that should be done through CSS. Aside from the global attributes, border is the only valid attribute for table elements; though even border should be done using CSS. The WHILE loop in the first should be done with a FOR loop.

The PHP in all blocks use the depreciated mysql_query, so they really aren't proper.

The SQL in the all blocks are obviously vulnerable to SQL injection; you should be using prepared statements, parameterized queries, or AT LEAST a mysql_real_escape_string.